# Why does Amazon make you enter specified digits upon calling their customer service switchboard?

Tags: phone, captcha

If one calls the Amazon customer services number, a robotic voice asks one to enter three numbers. Along the lines of “to be connected to a customer service associate, please press [XYZ]” (where [xyz] may be any the specified numbers).

What is the purpose of this, is it a captcha? That’s the only thing I can think of yet audio captcha recordings on web pages are usually obscured by static. And these are not they’re just spoken clearly and normally with no noticeable obfuscation. But what purpose could these be for?